# Xcode8.3.1 swift3.1 build success but archive fail

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

Xcode8.3.1 swift3.1 build success but archive fail.
Did anyone have any idea?
[error screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsaXj.png)

Comment: swift3 not for `AnyObject` it should be `Any` Xcode suggestion fix that one

Comment: can you add you code snippet

Comment: Cast all `AnyObject`s to the actual types.

Answer (score 0):

Update your Xcode to 8.3.2. The new update will resolve this issue as I had the same problem with archive.

Comment: I have updated just now,but still fail when archive.

Comment: any other idea?@Akhil Nair

Comment: @CoderZyc I am looking into it.